# How to determine the collector current limiting resistors for the Darlington's pair of transistors?

Tags: transistors, resistors, ohms-law, darlington, electric-field

How were the resistors in the circuit calculated?, I would like to come up with a similar circuit but for a 5VDC power supply, and I would like to resize the resistors as per my load requirement, my load is just a single LED rated 20mA.

[image: schematic]

K. Daware, “Build your own non-contact voltage detector | jameco favorites,” JAMECO Electronics.  [Online]. Available: https://www.jameco.com/Jameco/workshop/JamecoFavorites/non-contact-AC-voltage-detector.html. [Accessed: 27-Nov-2023]

Comment: This is not exactly a darlington pair; typically a darlington pair's collectors are tied together with no resistors.

Answer (score 2):

They're not particularly critical. Most of the current consumption is in the output circuit.

You can use the same values except replace [220Ω + buzzer + LED] with [1.5kΩ + LED] for about 5mA through the LED.